# Chrome renders font size too big

Tags: css, font-size

I have problems with the following html/css code:

```css
body{
    font-size: 3.8em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

div{
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}

#title,#footer{
    background-color: #1e9e40;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.6em;
}

#footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#main{
    padding: 1.3em;
    background-color: #540054;
    margin-top: 2.5em;
    font-size: 0.65em;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

<title>css problems</title>

</head>

<body>
<div id="title">Title font should be smaller!</div>
<div id="main">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui     officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div id="footer">This is the correct font size!</div>
</body>

</html>
```

When you look at the rendered webpage in the Chrome developer mode with mobile view activated, the #title uses a larger font size than the #footer. I can't explain why. Can you? Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: I don't see the problem on Chrome (Windows 10). What browser/system are you using?

Comment: If you don't have a `<meta name="viewport" ...>` setting, then your mobile view is pretty much pot luck.

Comment: @AHaworth I'm using Chrome on Windows 10 as well (version 88.0.4324.104 with 64 bit). But make sure you are in mobile mode. First you need to get in developer mode (Ctrl+Shift+C) and then you have to switch to mobile mode (Ctrl+Shift+M). There choose for example Pixel 2 as device. But the problem occurs on many devices.

Comment: @Alohci You are right. But still I want to understand the problem. The two divs should have the same font size.

Comment: I would not recommend you to use ems or pxs for beginners. It is hard to maintain (ems). Here is the [example link](https://jsfiddle.net/nr8u7d3c/), where I have compared the ems vs rems vs pxs. I would recommend you to use rems or pxs unless you really understand how ems will behave yourself in multiple nested elements. Yeah, and `<meta name="viewport" ..>` will prevent you from this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some checking on your code.

I also tested for different mobile devices in Chrome developer mode, and the same effect was seen. In desktop display, the browser is using the default user agent stylesheet, so there is no apparent issue.

In mobile viewports though, there's scaling applied, based on the specific device. That will have a bearing on elements with relative sizing, such as `ems`.

Essentially, what's happening on the #footer div is because it has `position:absolute`, and so doesn't behave like a block-level element. If you were to set the same fixed height to `#header, #footer`, and no other changes to the code, the font sizing would also be the same for both.

Similarly, if you position the header with `position: absolute`, the font sizing will be the same as the footer. The font sizing in the `#header` and `#footer` divs is being computed off the parent element, which in this case in the `<body>` element. Since the `<body>` element is set with a relative unit (em) for the font-size, it is also affected by the user agent default styling for that device. You'll see this if you set the font-size in the `<body>` element to a fixed-size value, such as px, where the child elements will also be affected, and be sized the same in relation to this value.

As others have mentioned, if you add this tag to the header:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`, you will avoid these sizing issues, since it sets a scale value as a base. **I've also added a standards-compliant example below this.**

For easier reference, I've also put your supplied code into a runnable snippet:

```css
body {
  font-size: 3.8em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

#title,
#footer {
  background-color: #1e9e40;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.6em;
}

#main {
  padding: 1.3em;
  background-color: #540054;
  margin-top: 2.5em;
  font-size: 0.65em;
  text-align: justify;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="title">Title font should be smaller!</div>
<div id="main">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div id="footer">This is the correct font size!</div>
```

**To add to this, ideally, you would build the code semantically, that search engines and screen readers could easily parse**. This includes the page title wrapped in a `<h1>` tag, and body text in `<p>` tags, such as this:

```css
body {
  font-size: 3.8em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: #1e9e40;
  padding: 0.6em;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  padding: 1.3em;
  background-color: #540054;
  margin-top: 2.5em;
  font-size: 0.65em;
  text-align: justify;
}

footer {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Title font should be smaller!</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</main>
<footer>This is the correct font size!</footer>
```

For reference, the `<h1>` element is styled to look the footer text, including the same styling. There's a bit more margin around it at times, due to default user-agent styling being applied.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Can you explain a little bit more what the parant element of #title and #footer is in my case? I thought both is body but apparently it's not. Chrome shows me that the computed font-szie for body is 60.8px and the computed font-size for #footer is 30.4px. This is perfectly fine because I set #footer to 0.5em. But for #title the computed font-size is 45.3px. What is the parent here and why?

Comment: ```<body>``` is parent. You should not use ```position: absolute``` for the footer. If you want it fixed to the bottom, you should use ```position: fixed```. You could also replace ```<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">``` with just ```<html>``` since it is optional in HTML5 invalid in HTML4.01 and only required in XHTML.

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass Thanks for your advise. Once I understood what is going on I will accept the respective answer. So body is the parent to footer, okay. But what it the parent to title? The parent of header should have twice the computed font size of title itself. I'm confused that you tell me that i shouldn't use position: absolute because where I use position: absolute the font-size gets computed correctly.

Comment: Each ```<div>``` you have added has ```<body>``` as parent. Your code is not proper and that is why it is failing. I will provide an answer with what proper code would look like.

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass Using the answer of karolus I was able to come up with "proper" code  myself. For example by making the title absolute (or fixed) as well. But I don't see why my code is improper and I want to understand how the font-sizes in my code are computed. What is the formular behind it?

Comment: To be honest, you should remove positioning for each element and replace the ```<div>``` elements with ```<header> <main>``` and ```<footer>```

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain The formula behind what you have done is simply the result of something that it is unexpected to the browser because the code doesn't make sense. The inner workings of each browser is different. The best way to handle all of them is to write proper html.

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass Thanks for your endurance helping me. But I still don't understand why my code doesn't make sense even though your code looks better and does the job. Which rule am I breaking in my code?

Comment: You are adding CSS which isn't required. I think, after over a decade of experience with HTML, that you should focus on learning what is correct and completely let go of what is wrong. Please read about positioning elements, there are multiple resources where you can learn this. When you understand the purpose of the most basic positioning: ```static``` (default), ```relative```, ```absolute``` and ```fixed``` you will know when, if ever, you are required to use them.

Comment: I would also add, that setting IDs for all of those elements isn't advisable. As @TimothyAlexisVass relates, semantic HTML would be using `<header>`, et.al, and removing the absolute positioning of the footer. My first impression would have been to completely rewrite the code, but that wouldn't have answered the original question.

Comment: The content has now been edited by adding a snippet with semantic HTML code, and why it's being used.

Answer (score 2):

Having reviewed karulos answer again, he is telling you what is happening with your code, but not what is wrong and what is correct.

For what you are trying to achieve and while keeping some of what you have done, this would be proper HTML5 code:

There is no reason to add positioning to the body, header or footer at all. You could also keep the `<html>` tag like that without defining the xhtml namespace. You should also use `<header>`, `<main>`, and `<footer>` elements instead of `<div>`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 3.8em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

header, footer, main {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

header, footer {
  background-color: #1e9e40;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.6em;
}

main {
  padding: 1.3em;
  background-color: #540054;
  margin-top: 2.5em;
  font-size: 0.65em;
  text-align: justify;
}

footer {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <header>Title font has the correct font size</header>
  <main>And the rest of the code makes some sense...<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</main>
  <footer>This is the correct font size</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify different font size for different components or you can change the font size of desired element seperately as shown below

```css
body{
    font-size: 3.8em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

div{
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}

#title,#footer{
    background-color: #1e9e40;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.6em;
}

#title {
  font-size: 0.3em;
}

#footer{
//position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#main{
    padding: 1.3em;
    background-color: #540054;
    margin-top: 2.5em;
    font-size: 0.65em;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

<title>css problems</title>

</head>

<body>
<div id="title">Title font should be smaller!</div>
<div id="main">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui     officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div id="footer">This is the correct font size!</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you